# Dynamically determine http/https in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have below in my view

```php
@if($secure === true)
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
@else
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
@endif
```

and in my routes I have

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index', ['secure' => request()->secure()]);
});
```

Locally this works but when deployed to a secure site (using https) I receive an error

```
VM204:31 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-site/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#generating-urls This should answer your query.

Comment: @1ns4n3 I have tried above `url('/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes')`. This generates `http://localhost:8000/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes`

Comment: you should be able to omit the scheme altogether, so `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes` should serve both